# Changing all the indexes of all dataframes in a dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dictionary with a list of dataframes, each with a column that is in datetime format (column name "Datetime Format").  I am attempting to set the index of each dataframe to be that column, and am having difficulty.

I've simplified the issue and tried to find a solution, my technique is not sticking:

```
def test_func(dataframe):
    dataframe = dataframe.set_index('Datetime Format')
    return dataframe

test_dict = {'DF_1': df1, 'DF_2': df2}

for k, v in test_dict.items():
    v = test_func(v)
```

Upon looking at the resulting test_dict, or each individual dataframe (df1 and df2), I was not successful at setting the indexes to be the 'Datetime Format' column.

I know when I do:

```
df1 = df1.set_index('Datetime Format')
```

it works correctly.

Please advise as to how to get this to function through a list (or dict in this case).

Thank you!

Comment: `d={k :test_func(v) for k, v in test_dict.items()}`

Answer (score 0):

The `set_index` function returns a new DataFrame by default, which is why your changes aren't sticking.

There are two ways around this: you could re-assign the dict value with the DataFrame returned by the function.

```
for k, v in test_dict.items():
    test_dict[k] = test_func(v)
```

Or you could pass the `inplace` argument when calling `set_index`.

```
def test_func(dataframe):
    dataframe = dataframe.set_index('Datetime Format', inplace=True)
```

This will modify the original DataFrame, without creating a new version.